# Vue.js 2. Как можно сделать плавную анимацию используя v-for. (no JQ)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть страница с новостями, которая постоянно спустя 5 сек отправляет запрос на `/getNews`, ответ присваиваю в `items`. Далее через v-for происходит рендер блоков. Мне не нравиться, что они рендерятся сразу, я бы хотел какой нибудь плавности.

Код (News.vue):

```
<template>

    <div>
        <router-view></router-view>
        <div class="AddNews" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Are you have interested news? Add NEWS</div>
    <div class="GeneralBlock">
            <div v-for="item in items" class="newsBlock" v-bind:id="item._id">
                <div class="newsHeader">
                    <span class="spanNewsHeader" >{{item.title}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="newsBody">
                    <span class="spanNewsBody" >{{item.description}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data: () => {
            return {
                items: [],
                errors: []
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.getNews();
            setInterval(t => this.getNews(), 5000);
        },
        methods: {
            getNews: function () {
                axios.get('/getNews', { params: date}).then(res => {
                    if(res !== []) {
                        this.items = res.data.concat(this.items);
                    }
                }).catch(e => this.errors.push(e));
            }
        }
    }



</script>

<style>
    html {
        background-color:#fffacd;
    }
    html {
         background-color:#fffacd;
         transition: 0.3s all;
     }
    #app {
        padding-top: .1%;
        transition: 0.3s all;
    }

    .GeneralBlock {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 5%;
        transition: 0.3s all;
    }

    .newsBlock{
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        margin-top: 3%;
        margin-left: 50%;
        left: -25%;
        background-color:#FFFFF0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        transition: 0.3s all;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #addNews {
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
    .AddNews{
        position: absolute;
        height: 35px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        left: -25%;
        font-size: large;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #67b168;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #addNewsOpen {
        position: absolute;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: medium;
        margin-top: 0.5%;
        margin-left: 64%;
    }
    .newsHeader{
        position: inherit;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
        border: solid 0px black;
        margin-top: 0%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        transition: 0.3s all;
    }
    .spanNewsHeader {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 2%;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: x-large;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .spanNewsBody{
        word-wrap: break-word;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-justify-trim: normal;
    }
    .newsBody{
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: medium;
        transition: 0.3s all;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Чисто поставлю плюсик , так как щас нужно сделать тоже самое )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для анимации списков надо использовать transition-group.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

Основные моменты:

- элементы списка должны иметь уникальный ключ (задается через :key);
- по умолчанию элементы списка рендерятся в контейнер span, но это можно поменять использую атрибут tag;

И небольшой пример:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        items: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
   setTimeout(() => {
        this.items = [
        {id: 1, text: "Lorem ipsum"},
        {id: 2, text: "Lorem ipsum"},
        {id: 3, text: "Lorem ipsum"},
        {id: 4, text: "Lorem ipsum"},
        {id: 5, text: "Lorem ipsum"}
      ]
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}

.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.9s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(50px) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="list" tag="div">
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" class="item">
      {{item.text}}
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто, но есть еще минус. `transition-group` херит мои стили.

Должно быть так: http://www.imghost.in/img/2017-07/14/o3ykguycyr53o4wej31qce62n.png

  Но получилось так: http://www.imghost.in/img/2017-07/14/p2wjpqbq3ydznbdbju68ubfse.png

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать `<transition-group>` или `<transition>` для создания плавных переходов.

Подробности: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html